# generic function to return enum value

Tags: .net, enums

I have three different Enum and all of three has same identifier but different values.  I want to access particular enum based on some condition.

for example:

```
Public Enum Type1
     Font = 10
     Color = 11 
End Enum

Public Enum Type2
     Font = 20
     Color = 21
End Enum

Public Enum Type3
     Font = 30
     Color = 31
End Enum
```

And based on certain condition i need to access particular enum.  for example,

```
if(somecondition = 1) 
    return Type1.Font
else if (somecondition = 2)
    return Type2.Font
else if (somecondition = 3)
    return Type3.Font
```

I need to repeat same logic to access other enum identifier.  Is there any way I can write generic method that return me enum value?

for example,

```
public function GetEnumValue(enumtype, identifier) as integer

  return enumtype.identifier 

end function
```

Is there any way to write above generic function to return enum value?

**Updated:** I am looking for method like GetEnumValue(Type1,Font) that returns enum value in integer (in this case 10 for type1.font)

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is *extremely* unclear.

You may be looking for

```
return Enum.Parse(enumType, valueName);
```

Where `enumType` is a `Type` object and `valueName` is a string.

Comment: i think thats what i need.  I don't find "GetValue" method under Enum.  Is that enum identifier as a second parameter in that method?

Comment: @Shailesh: Sorry, `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: Thanks SLaks.  here is what I use Convert.ToInt32(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(Type1), "Font"))

Answer (score 3):

IMO you're misusing enums. You should have one `enum` and either

- three functions with a switch
- three dictionaries from your enum to int
- decorate each entry in the enum with attributes for the desired values.

Your immediate problem can be solved with [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)